# How can i make my grid system to work with negative?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

So I made a 2D grid system in unity, it can check tilemaps to see if there is a collision tile but only if my tiles is on a set of positive coordinates. I searched on my paper for 2 hours now, and I don't seem to find any good solution to solve my problem.

PS: my grid is an array of (int, int) but it seems that I must change the datastructure to support my negative coordinates.

So i tried first to offset my grid by the position of the tile that is in the left-bottom corner
but it did not work (i was expecting it to offset my whole grid and not just make a nullpointer error).

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]. Please add enough code to create a [mre]

Comment: hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve and what you struggle with ... but if it is only about the indices you can simply wrap around if you get negative or too big indices like e.g. (`var fixedIndex = ((index % maxIndex) + maxIndex) % maxIndex;`) .. this wraps around the index in both positive and negative direction

Answer (score 0):

Arrays only have positive indices.

If you have a fixed number of tiles, but want your origo at some other point than a corner tile, you can simply use a `Vector2Int` to define your origo. Add this offset to your tile indices to get the corresponding indices for your array. A helper class might be useful to ensure this is done whenever accessing the tile.

If you want to use arbitrary number of tiles you should instead switch to something other than an array. For example a dictionary: `Dictionary<Vector2Int, MyTileClass>`. This lets you store tiles with arbitrary coordinates, but you need to pay attention since there is nothing to guarantee that a tile with any specific indices exists.